# Form validation in addition to YUI

Tags: yui, validation

I'm in the process of adding some much needed client side form validation to a website I'm working on. We're currently using YUI. YUI doesn't have any form validation built in as I can see(prove me wrong).

I googled it

http://code.google.com/p/yui-form-validator/

It's not important that it's a YUI-extension as long as it plays along with YUI in a civilized manner.

What should I go for? Anyone out there with experience and an opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we'll go for http://validatious.org/
Lightweight and standalone. Will not interfere with YUI.

Answer (score 0):

There's a module in the gallery: http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/form

I haven't used it, but it looks pretty good to me.